# Aframe in sandbox

Tags: aframe

I am trying to run Aframe in a sandbox that doesn't allow the modification of built in javascript objects. It causes an error as it tries to add a polyfill Math.sign

How can I change this and other built-in object changes when building Aframe (0.6.0)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what a Sandbox means in your context? A-Frame assumes a browser environment with standard APIs like Math for instance that is available in all major browsers. A-Frame itself creates an AFRAME global object.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos The sandbox I am using is Google caja, it does not allow the modification of built-in js objects